# SQL Select statement check condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How should i go about doing something like:

IF the following select has any rows

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
```

then return that actual select, otherwise use another select statement.

I use somwthing like

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID)
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
ELSE
    SELECT QTY FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
```

but this way i use the first select twice(once in the check and once the actual return record set.

Comment: Does ID uniquely identify a row in `TABLE`? Is the `ELSE` condition selecting from the same table (if so, it will always evaluate as 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as inefficient as you think.  The EXISTS keyword means that the optimiser stops after 1 record is found.

But, if you really want to avoid repetition, you can do something like...

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID

IF (@@rowcount = 0)
    SELECT QTY FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
```

The problem here is that you now return up to 2 record sets to the client.  The first of which my be empty *(but field headers, etc, are still returned - just with 0 records)*.

You could avoid that by inserting results into a table variable, and only returning them to the client if there are any records.  But I think it would be noticeably slower than just using EXISTS() like you already do.

Comment: The shape of the two result sets is different anyway, so no point trying to coerce them together. I was going to post this exact same thing.

Comment: I don't agree: `EXISTS` doesn't instruct the optimiser to do anything as specific as "stop after 1 record is found" (which obviously is impossible given the empty set :)

Comment: @onedaywhen - All SQL is an expression of logic at a higher level of abstraction than that it is actually executed at.  EXISTS() is syntax for `0 records equates to false, any more equates to true`.  SQL Server's optimiser is sufficiently efficient that it terminates execution if any record is ever found when providing results as part of an EXISTS() operation.  In short, I dis-agree with your dis-agreement ;)

Comment: I agree with your last comment except for the last sentence :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @ID INT, 
        @NAME VARCHAR(50);

SELECT @ID = ID, 
       @NAME = NAME 
FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID;

IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 1) 
  SELECT @ID AS ID, @NAME AS NAME
ELSE   
  SELECT QTY FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
```

Comment: Good idea if the first select is guaranteed to return at most one row but won't work as written at the moment. You need to assign `Name` to a variable as well. And then have conditional logic to either select the variables or do the other select. And also this is MySQL syntax...

Comment: Concerning MySQL: BUSTED! (But I assumed this to be universal) Please feel free to edit the syntax. Concerning the workflow: If the first Query does NOT return any rows, the second will. Oups! Just s/<>/= in the IF

Comment: I took the liberty of editing it to work in SQL Server. Feel free to roll it back of course if I mangled your intent.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks! What about the UNION version?

Comment: @EugenRieck - UNION requires the same columns in all sets being UNIONed.

Comment: Idea is: Dataset has allways the same structure, test for name=="" to find out meaning of int field

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks (As you might have guessed I am a MySQL guy with curiosity about SQL Server). Is not being able to assign AND return a field not quite a massive limit on query creativity?

Comment: Only occasionally does it occur to me that it might be quite useful. Guess it comes up more often in MySQL in simulating the `OVER` clause.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, you just gave me something to google! Curiosity not only killed the cat, but it also comes at a time premium. Anyway, willing to pay that.